# Inconsistent window.onerror return true / false between browsers - any list of correct return values available?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, onerror

I understand there is some inconstancy between what window.onerror should return if we do not want to invoke the browsers javascript error handler.

Since our site is fairly ajax heavy, we need to make sure the browsers error handler is not invoked **ever**.

What I mean by this:

```
window.onerror=function(){
    console.log('error captured');
    return false;
}
```

The "return false" part, apparently, differs browser to browser.

Does anyone know of somewhere we can find a list of how this is handled browser to browser, something a-la quirksmode / caniuse?

Or if the list is fairly small, does anyone know the values needed to be returned to suppress each browsers error handler off the top of their head?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have your work cut out for you.

First off, you return `true` from your `onerror` handler, not `false`... Think of it as the browser is asking you if it should stop.

Next, there are some versions of some browsers that just tank in this area.  They just don't work as advertised sometimes, no one seems to know why.  The most intelligent answer I've ever seen is about call stack sizes getting too big... it sounded good to me!

That said, this should do the trick:

```
<script>
function stopErrors() {
    return false;
}
window.onerror = stopErrors;
</script>
```

Some key points from http://api.jquery.com/error/:

> Note: A jQuery error event handler should not be attached to the window object. The  browser fires the window's error event when a script error occurs. However, the window error event receives different arguments and has different return value requirements than conventional event handlers. Use window.onerror instead.

and

> The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error event ... Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

Comment: the ones we are most concerned with are as follow: <a href="/target" onclick="return ajaxTarget(...);">go</a> ... in this situation, unless the error is handled without invoking the browsers error handler, the browser will navigate to /target... we would MUCH rather handle this gracefully (and internally).

Comment: What kind of errors are you expecting – actual syntax errors in your code that might break the application, or just “data errors” regarding the content your AJAX request might retrieve? The latter you should handle in your code yourself, not via window.onerror.

Comment: I agree with cbore, but also, you should not be doing onclick="return ajaxTarget()">go</a>... it's bad practice, partly because if anything goes wrong, you can't prevent the click... instead use jquery to bind to the click event, call event.preventDefault() and then do your ajax stuff....